# How to ignore the letter case in email addresses using regex

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following script which runs as required taking email addresses from USERS sheet and matching them with the email address in the JOBS sheet but only when the letter cases of the email addresses are an exact match. I'm trying to add a regex to the script to ignore the letter cases however unsure how to go about this.

I have added the regex at
var companyValue = /[a-z][@][0-9]/i.users[indices[i]][3]

```
function updateUserData1() {  
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobSheet = ss.getSheetByName('JOBS');
  var userSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Zog54Yh3r5TyEaLLf3lHUbPGAikiu9HBOmBMtbbwwas").getSheetByName('USERS');
  
  // get products and jobs
  var users = userSheet.getRange("B2:O" + userSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var jobsRange = jobSheet.getRange("F2:AW" + jobSheet.getLastRow())
  var jobs = jobsRange.getValues()

  // get the list of products on the Jobs sheet and Product Codes on the products sheet
  var jobProducts = jobs.map(function(e){return e[7] })
  var prodCodes = users.map(function(e){return e[1]})
  // find the indices of every Job in the Product array
  var indices = jobProducts.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        prodCodes.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, i), new Map)
    );

  var priceArray = []

  // for each job get the Products index and the Price and push the price onto an array
  
  jobs.forEach((v,i) => {
    // assign value depending whether currency = Sterling or Euro
    if (jobs[i][7] !="" ){
      var companyValue = /[a-z][@][0-9]/i.users[indices[i]][3]
    }
    priceArray.push([companyValue])
  })
  jobsRange.offset(0, 1,jobs.length,1).setValues(priceArray)
```

Thanks for any solution

Comment: just make both lower case before comparing? Also, I don't see any comparison in your code. Is something missing from your post? Please reduce your post to just the minimum required for the question.

Comment: @ChristianFritz, yes best to make both lower case before comparing. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the sample input values of `jobProducts` and `prodCodes` and the sample output values `priceArray` you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike, the sample input values of jobProducts is "John@email.com", or "JOHN@EMAIL.COM". Sample output values priceArray is john@email.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide a proper response to the question, I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the issue was resolved from the comments section.

Not sure how you're doing the comparison but instead of adding regex it would be better to just convert the strings to lowercase before comparing. For this you can use the JavaScript method [`toLowerCase()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp).